# Как правильно согласовать?

Tags: согласование

Писала статью о судьбе Крыма (каким образом он очутился на Украине), в частности в тексте было такое предложение: "С распадом Советского Союза Украина, а вместе с ней и Крым, стала суверенным государством".
А вопрос, собственно, в том: правильное ли тут согласование? То есть, "стала суверенным государством" или "стали"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Желательно использовать следующий вариант: "С распадом Советского Союза Украина, а вместе с ней и Крым, стали суверенным государством".

Выбор мн. числа в подобных предложениях связан с препозицией подлежащего, состоящего из одноименных членов, связанных присоединительным союзом:  например: "Премьер-лига, а вместе с ней и весь российский футбол, стали политик-лигой". "И каждый раз Даша, а вместе с ней и вы, узнаете что-то совершенно новое". "Мировая экономика, а вместе с ней и торговля,  выходят из депрессии.

Comment: Может быть, подойдет такой вариант:"С распадом Советского Союза Украина, как и входящий в нее Крым, стали суверенным государством".

Answer (score 1):

Украина  стала  суверенным  государством.  А  Крым  на  тот  период  никаким  государством  не  был,  а  был  частью  УССР,  как  раньше  был  частью  РСФСР.

Answer (score 0):

**Украина, включая входивший в её состав Крым, стала независимым государством.**
Иначе Вам проблем с согласование числа сказуемого не избезжать.
"Украина, как и Крым, стала независимым государством" - это либо два суверенных государтва получается, либо, что еще хуже, претензия на то, что "Украина, как и Крым" - название этого государства. Набодобие "Боснии и Герцоговины".        
А "Украина, как и Крым, стали независимым государством" - это либо намеренное грамматическое рассогласование числа подлежащих и сказуемого, либо просто косноязычие.

[[@София](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)](/users/2203/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F), простите, почему-то не идут комментарии.

> Может быть, подойдет такой вариант:"С распадом Советского Союза Украина, как и входящий в нее Крым, стали суверенным государством".

Мне не нравится. Суверенным государством стала Украина, а не Украина и Крым, который был её частью.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, так лучше. В этом случае мы уходим от И.п., заменяя его В.п., и тогда не требуется согласование во мн. числе, можно сказать "Украина стала".